# Query within 2 numbers and on 2 different fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a class in Parse.com, that has an x and y field. Is it possible with one query to get all the objects that are say within `x = 10` and `x = 20` AND `y = 10` and `y = 20`?

Would the query be set up like this?

```
    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"myClass"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"x" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:leftEdge]];
    [query1 whereKey:@"x" lessThanOrEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rightEdge]];


    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"myClass"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"y" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:topEdge]];
    [query1 whereKey:@"y" lessThanOrEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bottomEdge]];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]];
```

Comment: Did you read https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/queryWithClassName:predicate: ?

Comment: I meant, this @"x >= 10 AND x <= 20 AND y >= 10 AND y <= 20" as predicate doesn't work?

Comment: I've not used predicates in queries before, I always go with the greaterThan/lessThan methods. I've updated my question, I thought something like my code example would be the way to go, but you're saying that just using a predicate would be fine?

Comment: Predicate or your greaterThan/... methods yeilds same results.